# Sent picture of my private parts

Tags: tawba

I had a guy friend who was of different religion and by his provocation I sent him my upper body pics without clothes he saw it several times after that I had a boyfriend whom i never met personally but he saw my private parts through pics several times too and then I got provoked by myself and sent my upper body picture without clothes to two completely strangers on a website but it had no option of deletation or saving or sharing  tho Ik it has no risk of being viral but i regret it so much and now i want to forget it do tawba and also wanna know if should tell this to my future husband.

Comment: This is not a confession site , please go through the guidelines of the website to frame a better question.  This is relevant https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8151/how-does-one-repent-in-islam

Comment: The action of something being haram doesn't depend on it going "viral" . Seek help from a friend or website owners on how to delete the media to your best ability

Answer (score 2):

As-salamu-Alaikum sister,

May Allah guide you nearer to him. It's good you're honest, and are asking to repent. Allah is more merciful than our parents, and surely he will forgive you if you really ask for it. Make an intention to never repeat this again, and pray for forgiveness from Allah, and he will forgive you if you are genuine.

As for your future husband, remember that Allah commands us to protect and shelter ourselves, even from ourselves. Put this behind you, and make the intention of protecting yourself and not making public your past mistakes even to your future husband.

With Allah's forgiveness, you will move on easily Insha'Allah